# Как сделать графическую загрузку изображений?

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю сайт, и в каждый пост нужно добавлять картинки, ну и я их добавляю лучше вам не знать как)

хочу сделать вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. как на OLX.ua
пример кода, или какие-то наброски бы мне)

Answer (score 1):

> Есть очень классный фрейморк-angularjs. Сперва сложно может будет
>   разобраться, но потом поймёте, что всякие там jquery и подобные рядом
>   и не валялись. Там,например, делаете запрос на сервер-получаете json и
>   в одном значении ссылка на фото. Можно прицепить это к модели, а
>   модель в html код. В итоге-делаете аякс запрос и изменяете модель. В
>   html можете вообще не лезть(ну если прописали сперва правильно
>   отображение нужных полей). В итоге разметка будет меняться сама, в
>   зависимости от количества элементов в модели после аякс запроса
>   например. Вы можете в разметке написать ng-src и привязать это к
>   модели. Картинки будут отображаться сами. Если вам надо просто плюсики
>   поставить, как на картинке- это вообще проще простого там делается. Ну
>   понимаю-звучит расплывчато. Но посмотрите в сторону этого фреймворка-
>   он действительно крутой.

Comment: Или Вас интересует разметка и css, как это сделать?

Comment: недавно хотел сделать поля в стиле ангулара, но никак не смог его подключить на сайт)

Comment: Ну например здесь написано- http://angular.ru/  ,а вообще гугл много находит

Comment: а как-то по-проще сделать, например так как тут

Comment: Ну да- я может предложил "пушку по воробьям", зато пушка неплохая))) Если Вы на jquery делаете, то в этой библиотеке есть опция вставить в определённый контейнер данные. Вы берёте один контейнер div(это у Вас прямоугольничек с шириной/высотой такой-то и в центре которого картинка) и вставляете его в другой контейнер (где будет много этих прямоугольничка ) Вот пример http://jquerybook.ru/api/.append()-fn16.html

Comment: я начинающий, это пока-что сложновато)

Comment: тут комментарии обновляются с помощью setInterval?

Comment: Опишите точнее- что Вы хотите получить и я постараюсь Вам помочь

Comment: ну пускай даже будет обычные поля для вставки изображений, где пользователь нажимает "Выбрать файл", выбирает картинку, и после нажатия опубликовать, выбранная картинка загружалась в определенную папку, а ее имя записывалось в бд. Как записать в БД и т.д это я знаю, но как получить имя файла картинки для записи в бд хз)

Comment: Т.к. вдруг два пользователя загрузят картинки с одинаковым названием-этот вариант не подходит. Я не загружал картинки на сервер(можете почитать как php файл принимает картинку), но смысл такой- на опред адрес отсылаете картинку и присваиваете ей id (например время timestamp+имя самого файла...да вообщем-как хотите, так и можете назвать) записываете этот id в базу и привязку-кто добавил, к какой теме принадлежит и т.д.  Потом просто выкидываете этот сгенерированный id.jpg и грузите этот файл

Comment: http://buka-web.blogspot.de/2010/10/jquery.html  Только должна быть подключена библиотека jquery

Comment: спасибо, буду разбиратся, если что напишу)

Answer (score 0):

если не парится и бистро

то можно сделать так

```
<label><input type="file"></label>
```

Стилизировать label как нужно, а input-у добавить прозрачность и растянуть на всю ширину и высоту label